# Limitations of the perfectly matched layers for the Schrodinger Equation due to nonlinear dispersion relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

Short version:

Does the nonlinear dispersion relation of the Schrodinger equation limit the applicability of absorbing boundary conditions (ABCs) based on perfectly matched layers (PMLs)?

Longer version:

One of the simplest ABCs is based on the one-way wave equation. If you have any wave $u\left(x,t\right)$ moving left with a velocity $v$, then we can write $u\left(x,t\right) = G \left(x + vt\right)$. That satisfies the one-way wave equation $\left(\frac{d}{dx} - \frac{1}{v} \frac{d}{dt} \right)u=0$. So, in a computer simulation, you can enforce the one-way wave equations at the edges of your computational domain to let waves with velocity $v$ leave the computational domain without reflecting.

That basic idea works well for electromagnetic waves in vacuum because all electromagnetic waves in vacuum have the same group velocity. However, the Schrodinger equation has, in general, a non-linear dispersion relation, so different frequency waves move at different group velocities, and the above one-way wave equation only works perfectly for a single group velocity.

So, the nonlinear dispersion relation of the Schrodinger equation limits ABCs based on the above one-way wave equation to work perfectly only for waves of a single group velocity. (The situation can be improved in various ways [[T. Fevens and H. Jiang, SIAM J. Sci. Comput. 21, 255 (1999)](https://doi.org/10.1137/S1064827594277053)], but the fundamental problem remains.)

My question is whether a similar problem happens to ABCs for the Schrodinger equation based on PMLs. The [wikipedia page for PMLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_matched_layer) seems to suggest 'yes' because it notes that the attenuation is proportional to $\frac{k}{\omega}$, which is constant for a linear dispersion relation, but not for a nonlinear dispersion relation. In particular, if $\omega \propto k^2$, then the attenuation constant goes to zero as $k$ increases. However, the wikipedia page also notes that there may be ways around this limitation by using an auxiliary differential equation.

(I've also heard the PMLs have trouble with backward-wave modes, where the group and phase velocity have opposite signs. Is this still true for Schrodinger equation PMLs?)

I would be interested in any references on the subject. I can find many papers that use PMLs for the Schrodinger equation, but I can't find much information on PMLs' limitations. FWIW, I'm only looking for limitations in the theory -- not limitations in numerical implementations.